# How can i start tomcat 8 on linux and run servlet?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have tried:

```
shibly@mybox:~/apache-tomcat-8.0.3/bin$ ./startup.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/shibly/apache-tomcat-8.0.3
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/shibly/apache-tomcat-8.0.3
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/shibly/apache-tomcat-8.0.3/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/shibly/apache-tomcat-8.0.3/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/shibly/apache-tomcat-8.0.3/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

Building from Netbeans, I have put `WebApplication1.war` in `/home/shibly/apache-tomcat-8.0.3/webapps` .
Then `http://localhost:8084/WebApplication1/` or `http://localhost:8084/WebApplication1/NewServlet` don't run anything. May be, tomcat isn't starting properly. Got `Unable to connect` error.

How can i fix it?

I can start apache tomcat from Netbeans. It runs the WebApplication1 properly from Netbeans.

Comment: What do you have at the home page of Tomcat, i.e http://localhost:8084 ?

Comment: Unless you changed the configuration, I guess tomcat would listen on port 8080.

Comment: @Berger, `Unable to connect` error

Comment: @Henry, How can i tell and run tomcat on 8084 port? Where would i have to configure it?

Comment: MIGTFY: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/server.html

Comment: Look at server.xml and see what port your tomcat uses.

Comment: @Henry, Can i start tomcat with 8084 port? I don't want to change port from server.xml.

Comment: @shibly why not exactly? Because you fear that automatic updates of the server will revert the server.xml to the default settings?